# ClassFormatError array size > 65535

Tags: java, static-block

I have one generated class which get this error. Inside this class, there is one huge static block (5000+ lines). I broke the block into several smaller static blocks but still got this error. Why is that

**Edit**
Code looks like:

```
private static final Map<Object, Object> nameMap = Maps.newHashMap();
static{
    nameMap.put(xxx);
    .... 5000 similar lines
    nameMap.put(xxx);
}
```

Comment: We'd be able to help much more if we could see the offending code.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) please?

Comment: look at compilier options or split up in more classes

Comment: I guess the operand stack is over 64Ki, but splitting into different methods should fix this. Unless there is a very good reason for this class to contain 5K lines, you *seriously* need to redesign.

Comment: @owlstead, As I mentioned. It's a generated class. I agree that splitting into different methods should fix this. My question is that I have a large static block(not method), and I've splitted it into several smaller static method but why I'm still getting this error?

Comment: There is a max size limit of 64K (bytecode size) for a Java method.  There is sort of an exclusion to this limit for the `static` block, but numerous ways you can trip over it.  I forget all of the ways, but there are several places where a 64K limit is imbedded in the architecture.  (Possibly it's the number of elements in the constant pool, or it's physical size.)

Comment: @HotLicks Added the source of the 64Ki bytecode "size limit" to the question that this question duped.

Answer (score 3):

If it is just data you will need to read the data in from a resource.

Arrange for your data file to be in the same location as the class file and use something like this:

```
class Primes {

    private static final ArrayList<Integer> NUMBERS = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String NUMBER_RESOURCE_NAME = "numbers.txt";

    static {
        try (InputStream in = Primes.class.getResourceAsStream(NUMBER_RESOURCE_NAME);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                String[] numberStrings = line.split(",");
                for (String numberString : numberStrings) {
                    if (numberString.trim().length() > 0) {
                        NUMBERS.add(Integer.valueOf(numberString));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Loading of static numbers failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this to read a comma separated list of 1000 prime numbers.

Comment: Are you posting this to the correct question?

Comment: @owlstead - If it is just data then this should fix the problem. There seems to be no indication of the nature/content of the *huge static block* mentioned. Title does mention *array size*.

Comment: @owlstead The spotty problem description really does sound like the OP is trying to cram a large dataset into a static initializer for some reason. I can't think of any other vaguely legitimate reason for such a giant code block.

Comment: @owlstead Ayup, it's a data structure, and "don't do that" seems like an entirely reasonable answer to a question of how to deal with a class with so much constant data it's overflowing the symbol table.

Comment: @chrylis OK, fixed the issues with the code, hope that OldCurmudgeon will like the changes. Removed -1 vote. Did not see the added code block to the question before the answer...

Comment: @owlstead - thanks for the code tweaks - hate the Java shouty constants but that's probably just me - I hated the shouty C #defines too.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Even if Java is my favourite language, I hate tons of its features. But experience taught me to keep to the defaults, as I am just this guy. And I've been proven incorrect time and time again when I tried to deviate :P My code is never just mine...